# How to access private specialized function?

Tags: scala

In lecture note, original source code is below

```
private val sort1 = {
   val method = scala.util.Sorting.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(”sort1”, classOf[Array[Int]], classOf[Int], classOf[Int])    
   method.setAccessible(true)
   (xs: Array[Int], offset: Int, len: Int) => {
       method.invoke(scala.util.Sorting, xs, offset.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], len.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) 
   }
}
```

But, sort1 is deprecated in current scala version.

So, I want to use insertionSort instead.

[src/library/scala/util/Sorting.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9aae16aa231ad64e3987aaad2a206beaf10c76e0/src/library/scala/util/Sorting.scala)

```
private def insertionSort[@specialized T](a: Array[T], i0: Int, iN: Int, ord: Ordering[T]): Unit = {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why anyone would need such hack? It seems to break the API principles to me

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I just wondering is it possible and how to. Now, I knew the correct signature is listed in Sorting$.class file. I'm very new to scala or java I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this reflection, but don't. *Please* don't. Private methods are private for a reason. The implementation could change, could be taken away, or anything else. Using private methods is a very bad form of binding we avoid by making them private in the first place. That is, we aren't supposed to know what's going on under the hood of a class's private methods. Writing code that does so is extremely fragile and volatile.

If you're really interested in how, read on, but the best thing to do would be to stop right here and try something else.

Multiple versions of the `insertionSort` method are created (one for each specialized type). You can de-compile `scala.util.Sorting` to find the correct method with the correct signature. The one to use here is `insertionSort$mIc$sp`. Then, you can access it via reflection as desired.

```
val sort = {
   val method = scala.util.Sorting.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("insertionSort$mIc$sp", classOf[Array[Int]], classOf[Int], classOf[Int], classOf[Ordering[Int]])
   method.setAccessible(true)
   (xs: Array[Int], offset: Int, len: Int) => {
       method.invoke(scala.util.Sorting, xs, offset.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], len.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], implicitly[Ordering[Int]])
   }
}
```

But *please*, don't!